# _ptr or _var - which one use as a class field and why?

Tags: c++, corba, idl, omniorb

I have a class:

```
class Impl1 : public POA_I1
{
   private :
          Impl2_var ob;
   public :
          Impl2_ptr get();
          {
             return ob;
          }

          void set(::Impl2_ptr ob)
          {
             this->ob = ob;
          }
};
```

I'm a litte bit confused about `_ptr` and `_var`. I read that

> MyObject_var The _var version of the object reference type acts as a
>   handle toproxy in much the same way as a _ptr reference but also adds
>   memory management. Like all _var types, a _var reference takes care of
>   deallocating its underlying instance (in this case, the proxy
>   instance) when the reference goes out of scope. Both _ptr references
>   and _var references allow the client to access operations onproxy
>   instance

**but I dont understand when to use each one and why**. I mean, in my implementation = which one should I use, `_var` or `_ptr` and why? And is it legal to have a field of type `_var` in class and return `_ptr` in setter? I just don't get it at all.

Comment: The _var behaves as an auto_ptr. Normally we use _var as member, pass _ptr around. You have to use _duplicate() at the correct places, which takes time to learn. Another option is the IDL to C++11 language mapping, that is much easier to use, see http://www.orbzone.org for more details on that.

Comment: I would recommend you to check some existing CORBA examples shipped with omniORB or for example TAO. See how people have created their tests and learn from it. For _ptr/_var usage also run with for example valgrind to make sure you don't have any memory leaks.

Comment: @Johnny Willemsen: Yes, I've seen orbzone.org and it's seems pretty awesome and imo it's much easier to use than the old mapping. I have just one more question. Is it legal to assign `_ptr` to other `_ptr`? I've read that it's illegal to assign `_var` to `_var` (I just need to do it with `_duplicate()`) but I didn't found anything about assigning `_ptr` to `_ptr`

Comment: Yes, I believe it's legal. But I also thought it was legal to assign `_var` to `_var`

Comment: It is legal to assign a _var to _var, but the tricky part is that the reference count doesn't get incremented at that moment. It is more common CORBA programming to use a _duplicate() at that moment. It is also allowed to assign a _ptr to _ptr.

Comment: It is allowed to assign a _ptr to a _ptr, but you'll leak resources doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Johnny pointed out, it's all about memory ownership. If you assign an _ptr variable to an _var variable, when the _var variable goes out of scope the memory will be deleted and you better not use that _ptr variable.

In the case you provided, when you call `set` you are giving an object of type `Impl1` ownership of the pointer.  You can still use the one you have, you can call `Impl1::get` but since you gave the object ownership of that _ptr by calling `set`, if the object gets deleted so does the memory referenced by that pointer.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. So, you advise to use `_duplicate()` in setter methods, which takes as an argument a `_ptr`?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. `_var` types for object references implement reference counting. So when a `_var` type goes out of scope, the reference count is decremented. Only when the reference count goes to zero will `_release` be called.

Answer (score 1):

The current IDL to C++ mapping is pretty difficult and confusing. As always, consult the Henning & Vinowski book.

In general, do this for object references:

1. Always pass object references as `_ptr` types in function arguments.
2. But always store them (e.g. member variables, local variables) in `_var` types.

Comment: I think your general rule #1 applies only if the variable is not already in a `_var`, right?  Because if you create a `_ptr` out of a `_var` and pass the `_ptr` to something that puts in into a local `_var`, as soon as something's variables go out of scope, the original `_var` is hosed, no?

Comment: @jhfrontz: You usually combine this with a `duplicate` call so this scenario won't happen.  This is basically why the older C++ mapping is terrible.

Comment: How does the destructor of something's `_var` know that it should not destroy the underlying object?  Does the `_var` constructor somehow know that `_ptr` is referencing an object that is also referenced elsewhere by a `_var` and thus something's `_var` is in essence incrementing the reference count?

Comment: Oh, now I think I see it: `_var` is basically a `_ptr` with implied/automatic reference decrementing on destruction.