# Segmentation fault when returning a sequence CORBA C++ Server Java Client

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, corba

I'm developing a project in which I need to implement a Chat server in C++ and Chat clients in Java using swing for implementing the GUI.

I'm having exactly this problem, implementing nearly the same project:

[Segmentation fault CORBA C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919759/segmentation-fault-corba-c/23760891)

This is the part of my IDL where the problem is:

```
typedef sequence<ICliente> ListaClientes;

interface IServer
{
  attribute ListaClientes lista;
  void registrar_usuario (in ICliente cliente) raises (usuarioRegistrado);
  IConversacion crear_conversacion (in ICliente cliente);
  ListaClientes obtener_lista();
  void dar_baja(in ICliente cliente);
};
```

And then the part of the code where I'm getting the segmentation fault is this one:

```
ListaClientes* Server_i::obtener_lista() {
   return userList._retn();
}
```

Where:

```
ListaClientes_var userList=new ListaClientes(size);
```

---

Or:

```
ListaClientes* userList=new ListaClientes(size);


ListaClientes* Server_i::obtener_lista() {
   return userList;
}
```

Comment: can you paste a code of userList._retn() please?

Comment: its just code generated by omniorb when compiling the IDL. Trying to return a ListaClients* object directly also throws segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
ListaClientes* Server_i::obtener_lista() {
   ListaClientes_var my_list = new ListaClientes(size);
   my_list->length (size);
   // Fill the elements in the newly created sequence by doing a duplicate of each object reference as it exists in the member variable
    for(CORBA::ULong i=0;i<userList->length();i++){
      my_list[i] = ICliente::_duplicate(userList[i]);
    }
   return my_list._retn();
}
```

Comment: Or consider to use a product supporting the new IDL to C++11 language mapping.  There an IDL sequence maps to a std::vector and no _vars anymore. See for example http://swsupport.remedy.nl, we have free evaluation packages for Windows and Linux.

Comment: userList is a class variable, I can access its contents using userList->get_buffer()->nickname() for example, to print the client name, and it works through all the userList size. How do you suggest to Fill the elements in newly created sequence by doing a duplicate of each? I tried this: `for(int i=0;i<20;i++)`
        `aux._retn()->get_buffer()[i]->_duplicate(userList->get_buffer()[i]);`
`return aux._retn()` but it didn't work. Thank you, if I get even more crazy I'll have to try installing TAOX11.

Comment: You shouldn't use get_buffer(), that is all internal. You have to return a copy of the list

Comment: I'm using get_buffer because userList[i] is type ListaClientes& if I use userList->get_buffer()[i] it returns type _objref_ICliente* (that is ICliente_ptr). Using your code return the following error (that's why i was using get_buffer()) `no matching function for call to 'Chat::ICliente::_duplicate(Chat::ListaClientes&)`  `candidates are: static Chat::_objref_ICliente* Chat::ICliente::_duplicate(Chat::_objref_ICliente*)` . Thank you

Comment: Managed to solve the problem, you have to use the ListaClientes_var everywhere, you just can't use ListaClientes*, that was the problem, i had userList declared as ListaClientes*. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the _var everywhere. If you want to speed up your development, check http://swsupport.remedy.nl for TAOX11, really simplifies the development of CORBA based apps